# Drupal module not getting menu blocks?

Tags: 7, routes, hooks

I have a drupal module creating a new page using a menu hook. And I have menu blocks (menus displayed as blocks) that SHOULD be showing up on the drupal module page. But I cannot seem to get them to display? How can I get these menu blocks to show up? I tried added it to a menu and that did not work.

Create Menu

```
  $items['gift_cards'] = array(
    'title' => 'SELECT A CARD',
    'page callback' => 'uc_gift_certificate_order_page',
    'access callback' => 'user_access',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
```

This is the function to make the page, it is simply a drupal form.

```
function uc_gift_certificate_order_form($form_state) {
    // This is the function that generates the required page for ordering the gift card.
    // Load the required datepicker JS/CSS
    drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path("module", "uc_gift_certificate").'/datepicker/css/datepicker.css');
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path("module", "uc_gift_certificate").'/datepicker/js/datepicker.js');

    // We already have the block part (gift card rotator)
    // Display the form
    $form['#attributes'] = array('class' => 'gift-card');
    DRUPAL FORM API STUFF
}
```

Comment: can you provide sample code from your module?

Comment: Sure I edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Page callback should be `drupal_get_form` in your hook_menu and form definition handler should be passed as argument.

```
$items['gift_cards'] = array(
   'title' => 'SELECT A CARD',
   'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
   'page arguments' => array('uc_gift_certificate_order_page'),
   'access callback' => 'user_access', // no need to define in case of user_access
   'access arguments' => array('access content'),
   'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);
```